# Woocommerce - Change variations output

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

I'm looking for a way to **customize** the output of **the variations** selector.

For example, I have shirt size and **color**, and I want to transform the color field in a **custom radio button**, and **showing the color instead just text**

Comment: Please search before asking: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/ (and many others)

Comment: Thanks, I would mark this as the correct answer @LoicTheAztec